# Bodies not creating correct andengine

Tags: java, android, box2d, andengine

I am having with either my Physics World, ContactListener, or just my creation of bodies.

My issue is that I can create a body/sprite. The body and sprite are drawn correctly, and the player cannot walk through them, but collisions do not work with them. I had a method that had this problem, so to test the issue, when the player shot an arrow I created a body like this:

```
    Sprite testSprite = new Sprite(player.getX() + 100, player.getY() + 100,
            resourcesManager.wall_region, vbom);
    Body testBody = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, testSprite,
            BodyType.DynamicBody, PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0, 0));
    attachChild(testSprite);
    physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(testSprite, testBody));
    testBody.setUserData(new UserData("Tile", testSprite, 100, testBody));
    System.out.println(testBody);
```

These bodies/sprites create fine and I cannot walk through them. But the contact between these test bodies and arrows does not work correctly.

This is the collision in my ContactListener that should happen when an arrow and the tiles collide:

```
 if (((boolean) ((UserData) x1.getBody().getUserData())
                        .getType().equals("Tile"))
                        && ((boolean) ((UserData) x2.getBody()
                                .getUserData()).getType().equals("arrow"))) {
                    System.out.println("Tile/Arrow");
                    engine.runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            x2.getBody().setActive(false);
                            final Sprite sprite = (Sprite) ((UserData) x2
                                    .getBody().getUserData()).getSprite();
                            detachChild(sprite);
                            final PhysicsConnector physicsConnector = physicsWorld
                                    .getPhysicsConnectorManager()
                                    .findPhysicsConnectorByShape(sprite);
                            physicsWorld
                                    .unregisterPhysicsConnector(physicsConnector);

                        }
                    });
                }
```

But the weird thing is that it takes a while for this collision to register. For example, I could shoot 10 arrows at the testBody and they would just bounce off, but when I shot the 11th the above collision would happen.

Suggestions? I have been dealing with this issue for a long time and it is getting very frustrating, and I would be glad to provide more information if needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As per my view, I see many mistakes in this.

First you are creating bodies which have fixture properties like (0,0,0).
So what type of body this code create I can't able to understand!

First make this thing correct and apply proper value as per requirement.

If your assumption is to destroy body then write code for that means don't use active method.

The destroy code you have to write in thread so that it executed independently. So you have to maintain flag for destroy body so that same thread doesn't call two time.

**EDIT :** Create physics connector like this,

```
physicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(testSprite, testBody));
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I created these testBodies to simply test whether or not collisions were working because when my scene starts I create dozens of bodies just like this that serve as walls in my game, so the fixture properties are not the issue. However, if I create bodies after my initial bodies they seem to not work.

Comment: Also print user data of your receiving two bodies via string so that you can able to decide contact listener is calling or not? Directly inside begin contact method without any if condition. Also I see my edit of answer.